# Why is my bind9 totally messed up?

Tags: debian, bind

I'm completely dumbfolded by this situation, the deal is this:

I'm currently setting up an uml-instance of debian to work as a network server as part of a university course.

One part is installing a dns server (bind9 in this case) and I did this without any problems a few weeks ago.

Other services that are installed are ntp, nfs, nis and some simple raid setups.

A few days ago I installed an imap server on the machine (Courier) and while I didn't finish configurating it, everything seemed fine.

Today when I logged in I noticied that dns had stopped working, I checked the logs and noticed that /etc/bind directory was missing expect for rndc.key file.

Since I always hard-reset this machine I thought it was some sort of file system corruption, I checked the startup logs and saw some recovery messages.

The next step was to simply recreate the dns settings, I deleted /etc/bind and reinstalled bind, however when installing bind I get the following messages from apt:

```
wrote key file "/etc/bind/rndc.key"
chgrp: cannot access ´/etc/bind/named.conf* : No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ´/etc/bind/named.conf* : No such file or directory
```

I have no idea what to do next, any help is appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
apt-get purge bind9 
apt-get install bind9
```

and start over.

Oh yeah, and shutdown your system with `shutdown`.

Comment: Thanks, I used remove before, purge did a much better job! And yes, this sure teached me to be nicer to my machines ;)

Comment: Life saver, life saver, very useful to remove bind9 completely and reinstall, especially after the reached restart limit error.